# Lazy.from_fun and Lazy.from_val

Tags: ocaml

I am just curious about these two functions in `Lazy`.

#### Lazy.from_fun

From the doc:

```
val from_fun : (unit -> 'a) -> 'a t 

from_fun f is the same as lazy (f()) but slightly more efficient.
```

I then had a look at the source

```
let from_fun (f : unit -> 'arg) =
  let x = Obj.new_block Obj.lazy_tag 1 in
  Obj.set_field x 0 (Obj.repr f);
  (Obj.obj x : 'arg t)
```

I guess `Obj` is used to directly allocate memories for `from_fun`. But why exactly does it boost the efficiency? or what is the difference between `Lazy.from_fun` and `lazy (f())`?

#### Lazy.from_val

```
val from_val : 'a -> 'a t

from_val v returns an already-forced suspension of v. 
This is for special purposes only and should not be confused with lazy (v).
```

I really do not understand these. To me, `Lazy.from_val 5` and `lazy(5)` both  returns `int lazy.t` which has a concrete value of 5. Why is `Lazy.from_val` is for special purposes? and what kind of special purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just my guess: let's compare the following:

```
let z1 = lazy (print_newline ())
let z2 = Lazy.from_fun print_newline
```

using `ocamlc -dlambda`:

```
(setglobal Lz!
  (let
    (z1/1008 =
       (makemutable 246
         (function param/1012 (apply (field 31 (global Pervasives!)) 0a)))
     z2/1009 =
       (apply (field 2 (global Lazy!)) (field 31 (global Pervasives!))))
    (makeblock 0 z1/1008 z2/1009)))
```

`z1` is a lazy value created from a function of the code `function param/1012 -> Pervasives.print_newline ()`, while `z2` is created directly from `Pervasives.print_newline`. `z1` can be slightly inefficient because of the extra lambda abstraction.

Just as the documentation says, `Lazy.from_val` simply creates a lazy value from an already computed value without any suspension. You can check it by trying `Lazy.from_val (print_string "hello")` and `lazy (print_string "hello")`. The former immediately prints `hello`, but the latter does not.